# Limit under the integral doubt$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_\limits{-n}^{n}\frac{1-e^{-nx^2}}{x^2(1+nx^2)}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Compute the following integral $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_\limits{-n}^{n}\frac{1-e^{-nx^2}}{x^2(1+nx^2)}dx$$.

- Solution:*
  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_\limits{-n}^{n}\frac{1-e^{-nx^2}}{x^2(1+nx^2)}dx=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{n}\int_\limits{0}^{n}\frac{1-e^{-nx^2}}{x^2(1+nx^2)}dx$ since the function is even. Substitution $\sqrt{n}x=y$
  So we get after some adjustments: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\int_\limits{0}^{n\sqrt{n}}\frac{1-e^{-y^2}}{y^2(1+y^2)}dy$ 
  As $1-e^{-y^2}\sim y^2$. The expression converges uniformly then:

  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_\limits{-n}^{n}\frac{1-e^{-nx^2}}{x^2(1+nx^2)}dx=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_\limits{-n}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\frac{1-e^{-nx^2}}{x^2(1+nx^2)}dx=0$

**Question:**

So as far as I understand if I major an integral with a convergent integral then I can pass the limit under the integral? Where can I find the proof of this?
I have been searching for it but I have not found it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem might help you

Comment: From the analysis presented in the OP, the limit was never passed under the integral.  But you might be thinking of The Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Note that $\left|\frac{1-e^{-nx^2}}{nx^2(1+nx^2)}\right|\le\frac{1}{(nx^2)^2+3(nx^2)+1}\le \frac{1}{x^4+3x^2+1}$, which is integrable.  So, the DCT allows us to interchange the limit and the integral and arrive at the result reported.

Comment: @MarkViola Sorry, but it is not supposed to use results from measure and integration theory. Is there any other theorem besides DCT, that proves the statement. Thanks for the replies!